# Set &viminfo differently in neovim and vim

Tags: neovim

My current `&viminfo` contents are:

```
:set viminfo?
```

> viminfo=!,'100,<50,s10,h,n/home/ravi/.local/share/vim/viminfo

I want to have a single `vimrc` which works with both `vim` and `neovim`.

What lines can I add to my `vimrc` to set use:

- In `vim`: `/home/ravi/.local/share/vim/viminfo`
- In `neovim`: the [default](https://neovim.io/doc/user/starting.html#shada-file-name)

Comment: See the issues [3469](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/3469) and [3736](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/3736)

Comment: Thanks, I have already - my question is about how to implement a different `,n<name>` depending on whether I'm in `vim` or `neovim`.

Comment: @TomHale So your question is a duplicate of [this one](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/9064/1841) right?

Comment: While the resolution is in the "duplicate", I believe that this question has a bunch of valuable information which will help people in determining: 1) The cause of `E576` is `&viminfo` 2) Why and 3) What to do about it while keeping `viminfo` set as desired when using `vim`.

Comment: Should I open a question about `E576` and answer it myself?

Comment: I create a question about the cause of the `shada` `E576` [here](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/10028/5324)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest appending your specific additions to the viminfo option rather than duplicating default information.  That is, `set viminfo+=!`.

Additionally, it seems like setting the `n` option isn't necessary.  However, if you want to do that then you can simply do that in a non-nvim check.

```
if !has('nvim')
  set viminfo+=n~/.local/share/vim/viminfo
endif
```

Comment: Thanks - I now get clean `neovim` startup. Winning at life.