# E576: Failed to parse ShaDa file: extra bytes in msgpack string at position 3

Tags: neovim, startup

I'm switching from `vim` to `neovim`, but when starting `neovim`, I get the following error on startup:

> E576: Failed to parse ShaDa file: extra bytes in msgpack string at position 3

What does this mean, and how do I stop `neovim` complaining about it?

Note: I want to be able to use both `vim` and `neovim` with the same `vimrc`.

Answer (score 7):

TL;DR: skip to the `Resolution` section.

#### Background

The issue is that `neovim` can't read/write `vim`'s `viminfo` file format.

Instead of using `vim`'s`viminfo` format for storing editing session information, `neovim` uses a [shada-file](https://neovim.io/doc/user/starting.html#shada-file) for "SHAred DAta".

The default [shada file name](https://neovim.io/doc/user/starting.html#shada-file-name) is `$XDG_DATA_HOME/nvim/shada/main.shada`, and `$XDG_DATA_HOME` is `~/.local/share` by [XDG default](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html), giving a default `shada` file named:

```
~/.local/share/nvim/shada/main.shada
```

#### Cause

In `neovim`, `&viminfo` is a deprecated alias to the [`'shada'`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/options.html#'shada') option, which configures the [`shada-file`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/starting.html#shada-file)'s location and usage. This means that `neovim` will look at the `viminfo` variable for information about `shada` data.

This is generally fine - it's good for backward compatibility to store/recover the same information that `vim` would... except in the case where a file name is specified - a file which will probably contain `viminfo` data, not `shada` data.

The culprit is your `viminfo` variable (or possibly your `shada` variable), where you've explicitly set a filename to be used for the `viminfo` (or `shada`) file.

This file that you are referencing is in `viminfo` format, not `shada` format.

For example:

```
:set viminfo?
```

> ```
> viminfo=!,'100,<50,s10,h,n~/vim/viminfo
> ```

In your `vimrc`, you probably have a line like:

```
set viminfo+=n~/vim/viminfo
```

Where `n<name>` sets the file to be `<name>`.

The issue is that the file named `<name>` contains data in `viminfo` format.

#### Resolution

You can either:

1. Remove the line which explicitly sets the `viminfo` file name, in which case:

   - `vim` will use `~/.viminfo`
   - `neovim` will use `$XDG_DATA_HOME/nvim/shada/main.shada`

   or
2. Keep the existing file name when running `vim`, and use another when using `neovim`:

   ```
   if !has('nvim')
     set viminfo+=n~/vim/viminfo
   else
     " Do nothing here to use the neovim default
     " or do soemething like:
     " set viminfo+=n~/.shada
   endif
   ```

Answer (score 0):

in case your are using both of `vim` and `neovim`, put the following line into your `.vimrc` file.

```
" change default viminfo file locatoin
if !has('nvim') | set viminfo+=n~/.config/vim/viminfo | endif
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I got this error for the same reason, but I found [a simple solution](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/3469#issuecomment-265002804); remove this file: `~/.local/share/nvim/shada/main.shada`